# How to convert Unicode Escape Sequence to Unicode String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a string like `"\3619\3657\3634\3609\3648\3592\3657\3648\3621\3657\3591"` which I want to decode it. I tried search the unicode library without success.

Comment: How exactly should the reult look?

Comment: `Char` supports Unicode. If you `putStrLn` or write to any other handle, the result will display the proper unicode string, if the handle supports it. However, when you call `show` on a string, it always displays unicode codepoints as a backslash with the number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Prelude> putStrLn "\3619\3657\3634\3609\3648\3592\3657\3648\3621\3657\3591"
>   ร้านเจ้เล้ง

Note that you don't actually have the string `"\3619\3657\3634\3609\3648\3592\3657\3648\3621\3657\3591"` – rather, you have the UTF-32 string `ร้านเจ้เล้ง`, for which `"\3619\3657..."` happens to be a ASCII-compliant literal. By default, GHCi uses the `Show` instance to display results, which doesn't so much show things as *spit out literals that can be used as Haskell code for the thing*. It's conservative in terms of unicode. That's why

> Prelude> "ร้านเจ้เล้ง"
>   "\3619\3657\3634\3609\3648\3592\3657\3648\3621\3657\3591"

On the other hand, the `putStrLn`, `putChar`, `hPutStr` etc. functions will just dump the string itself in UTF-8 rather than an ASCII-safe representation thereof.

If you're actually reading the escaped string from a file or something, you can simply *read* it:

> Prelude> s <‌- getLine
>   "\3619\3657\3634\3609\3648\3592\3657\3648\3621\3657\3591"
>   Prelude> s
>   "\"\\3619\\3657\\3634\\3609\\3648\\3592\\3657\\3648\\3621\\3657\\3591\""
>   <sup>-- Note double escaping, because I'm showing a string that contains a string literal.</sup>
>   Prelude> putStrLn $ read s
>   ร้านเจ้เล้ง

Comment: One detail - they attempt to dump the string using the encoding the locale is set to, not always UTF-8.  You're just insane if you're using a locale that doesn't set to UTF-8. :)

Comment: @Carl, insane, or maybe just Asian. There are still a couple popular non-Unicode encodings out there, notably Big-5 and Shift JIS.

Comment: @Carl UTF-16 is also reasonable if you're dealing with a large amount of CJK.

Comment: @Pharap not really though. In most situations even on CJK the overhead of UTF-8 over UTF-16 doesn't matter. In those cases where it does matter, you probably shouldn't be using _either_ of them but instead either a compressed format (if storage is the problem) or some rope data structure and/or UTF-32 (if random-position-access is the problem).