# Is there a way to always see the glyphs for Unicode characters in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, unicode

Why do I sometimes fail to see the Unicode representation of characters in Haskell. For example I get

```
ghci>let b = "β"
ghci>print b
"\946"
ghci>putStr b
β
```

Is there a way to always get `β`? Are Unicode characters always represented as character code strings, and "converted" to glyphs by some functions (e.g. `putStr`; others perhaps)?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24953125/791604)? I could close it myself, but I'm not sure on this one. What do you think, @raxacoricofallapatorius? Does it explain enough for you to understand what you're seeing here?

Comment: @DanielWagner: Yes, that does it!