# Convert Text to Unicode Escape Sequence

Tags: haskell, unicode, character-encoding

I have a `Text` object that contains some number of Latin characters that needs to be converted to a unicode escape sequence of the format `\u####` with `#` being hex digits

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953125/how-to-convert-unicode-escape-sequence-to-unicode-string-in-haskell), haskell easily converts strings to escape sequences and vice versa. However, it will only go to the decimal representation. For example,

```
> let s = "Ñ"
> s
"\209"
```

Is there a way to specify the escape sequence encoding to force it to spit out in the correct format? i.e

```
> let s = encodeUnicode16 "Ñ"
> s
"\u00d1"
```

Comment: Trying to understand what you're asking for here, you're looking for 1) a function `Text -> Text` that 2) you are assuming will only be passed a value containing `Data.Char.isLatin1` matching `Char`s in order to 3) replace `not . Data.Char.isAscii` `Char`s with `Text` strings containing that `Char`'s c-style four digit form backslash-u encoding representation? E.g., `f "El Niño" = "El Ni\\u00f1o"`, nb the escaped backslash.

Comment: @RowanBlush That is an excellent summary, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
import Text.Printf (printf)

encodeUnicode16 :: String -> String
encodeUnicode16 = concatMap escapeChar
  where
    escapeChar c
        | ' ' <= c && c <= 'z' = [c]
        | otherwise =
            printf "\\u%04x" (fromEnum c)
```

I ghci, you can use it as follows:

```
> putStrLn $ encodeUnicode16 "Ñ"
\u00d1
```

Note that if you don't use `putStrLn` it will get escaped twice:

```
> encodeUnicode16 "Ñ"
"\\u00d1"
```

This is because ghci will implicitly add a `print` in front of the command.

**Edit**: I missed that part that you have a `Text` and not a `String`. Here's the same code for `Text`:

```
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Text.Printf (printf)

encodeUnicode16 :: Text -> Text
encodeUnicode16 = T.concatMap escapeChar
  where
    escapeChar c
        | ' ' <= c && c <= 'z' = T.singleton c
        | otherwise =
            T.pack $ printf "\\u%04x" (fromEnum c)
```

Again, you want to use `T.putStrLn` to avoid double escaping everything.